# jQuery accordion remove siblings class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am able to change the CSS when I clicked on a title to expand a menu. However other 'header' which has been expanded are unable to change to "inactive" class. 
Below is my HTML

```
<dt class="productsCat"><a href="/" class="productsName">Category 1</a></dt>
<dd class="subCat"><a href="<?php echo $subCategory->getUrl()?>">Sub Category 1</a></dd>
<dt class="productsCat"><a href="/" class="productsName">Category 2</a></dt>
<dd class="subCat"><a href="<?php echo $subCategory->getUrl()?>">Sub Category 2</a></dd>
```

And here is my jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").click(function(){
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast");
jQuery(this).parent().removeClass("productsCat");
jQuery(this).parent().addClass("openSub");
return false;
});
});
```

Any advice how I should remove the class "openSub" and use the existing class "productsCat" from all the other siblings when one is active?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, try this, works in my local..

```
$(function() {
$("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
$("dl#narrow-by-list > dt").first().addClass('openSub');
    $(".productsName").click(function () {

        if(!$(this).closest('dt').hasClass('openSub')) {
            $("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
        }
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast");
        $(this).parent().each(function () {

        $(this).parents('dl').find('dt').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('productsCat');
            $(this).removeClass('openSub');
        });     

        $(this).closest('dt').toggleClass('productsCat openSub');

    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not shure what you want, but maybe something like this? Else you could try the toggleclass?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:not(:first)").hide();
jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dt a").click(function () {
    jQuery("dl#narrow-by-list> dd:visible").slideUp("fast");
    jQuery(this).parent().next().slideDown("fast");
    jQuery(this).parent().each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('productsCat')) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('productsCat');
            jQuery(this).addClass("openSub");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, but the problem still exists. I can;t seem to be able to remove the class "openSub" for other menus which has collapsed.

Comment: Could you upload it so i can have a look?